# Calendario JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou a ciar um calendario em JavaScript. Quero mostrar todos os meses do ano. O meu problema é que o primeiro mes funciona bem, mas os restantes nao ficam nos dias correctos. Passo por parametro o numero de cada mes que ta no array.

```
    function calendar(mois){

        var date = new Date();
        var day = date.getDate();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var year = date.getYear();

        if(year<=200)
        {
                year += 1900;
        }
        months = new Array('Janvier', 'F&eacute;vrier', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Ao&ucirc;t', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'D&eacute;cembre');
        days_in_month = new Array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);

        var moisaujorduiu = month;

        month = mois;

        //ano bissesto, muda dia fevereiro
        if(year%4 == 0 && year!=1900)
        {
                days_in_month[1]=29;
        }


        total = days_in_month[month]; //days month

        var date_today = day+' '+months[month]+' '+year;//22 ouctober 2014

        beg_j = date; //today date

        beg_j.setDate(1);


        if(beg_j.getDate()==2) //1
        {
                beg_j=setDate(0);
        }
        beg_j = beg_j.getDay();

        document.write('<table class="cal_calendar"><tr><th colspan="7">'+months[mois]+' '+year+'</th></tr><br>');
        document.write('<tr class="cal_d_weeks"><th>Dim</th><th>Lun</th><th>Mar</th><th>Mer</th><th>Jeu</th><th>Ven</th><th>Sam</th></tr><tr>'); 
        week = 0;

        for(i=1;i<=beg_j;i++)
        {
                var beforemonth = months[month-1]; 

               document.write('<td><div class ="divday" />'+(days_in_month[month-1]-beg_j+i)+'</div></td>');
                week++;
        }
        for(i=1;i<=total;i++)
        {
                if(week==0)
                {
                    document.write("<tr>");
                }

                if(day==i && moisaujorduiu==month) //si le jour = le jour de aujordhui est si le mois = mois aujordui 
                {

                    document.write("<td><b><div class ='divtoday' onclick='open_popup(\""+i+" "+months[month]+"\")' href='#'>"+i+"</div><b></td>"); //day of today
                }
                //les autre jours
                else
                {

                    document.write("<td><div class ='divday' onclick='open_popup(\""+i+" "+months[month]+"\")' href='#'>"+i+"</div></td>");
                }
                week++;
                if(week==7)
                {
                        document.write('</tr>');
                        week=0;
                }
        }

            //pour les jour du prochain mois

             for(i=1;week!=0;i++)
            {
                    var nextmonth = months[month+1];
                    document.write('<td><div class ="divday">'+i+'</td>');
                    week++;
                    if(week==7)
                    {
                            document.write('</tr>');
                            week=0;
                    }
            }
        document.write('</table>');
```

Depois crio uma tabela, para por cada mes numa celula e chamo a funcao com parametro.

```
<table border=0 width=100% height=100%>
        <tr>
            <td>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var mois = 0; //janvier
                        calendar(mois);
                    </script>
            </td>
            <td>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var mois = 1; //fevrier
                calendar(mois);
                </script>
            </td>
            <td>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var mois = 2; //mars
                    calendar(mois);
                </script>
            </td>
            <td>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var mois = 3; //avril
                    calendar(mois);
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>    
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var mois = 4; 
                    calendar(mois);
                </script>
            </td>
            <td>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var mois = 5; 
                    calendar(mois);
                </script>
            </td>
            <td>    
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var mois = 6; 
                    calendar(mois);
                </script>
            </td>
            <td>    
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var mois = 7; 
                    calendar(mois);
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>    
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var mois = 8; 
                    calendar(mois);
                </script>
            </td>
            <td>    
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var mois = 9; 
                    calendar(mois);
                </script>
            </td>
            <td>    
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var mois = 10; 
                    calendar(mois);
                </script>
            </td>
            <td>    
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var mois = 11; 
                    calendar(mois);
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá, é simples seu problema.
Você está atribuindo sempre um dia na variável

```
beg_j = date; //today date
beg_j.setDate(1); //<--- passando um único dia
```

Sendo que deve passar o total de dias que teve somando todos os meses

Fiz o seguinte ajuste:

```
if(month > 0) { 
    soma = 0;
    for(var m=0; m<month; m++) {
        soma += days_in_month[m];
    }
    beg_j.setDate(soma+1);
}
else {
    beg_j.setDate(1);
}
```

Teste e veja se funciona. Espero ter ajudado

Segue a função JavaScript Atualizada:

```
function calendar(mois){

    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getYear();

    if(year<=200)
    {
            year += 1900;
    }
    months = new Array('Janvier', 'F&eacute;vrier', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Ao&ucirc;t', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'D&eacute;cembre');
    days_in_month = new Array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);

    var moisaujorduiu = month;

    month = mois;

    //ano bissesto, muda dia fevereiro
    if(year%4 == 0 && year!=1900)
    {
            days_in_month[1]=29;
    }


    total = days_in_month[month]; //days month

    var date_today = day+' '+months[month]+' '+year;//22 ouctober 2014

    beg_j = date; //today date

    if(month > 0) { 
        soma = 0;
        for(var m=0; m<month; m++) {
            soma += days_in_month[m];
        }
        beg_j.setDate(soma+1);
    }
    else {
        beg_j.setDate(1);
    }


    if(beg_j.getDate()==2) //1
    {
            beg_j=setDate(0);
    }
    beg_j = beg_j.getDay();

    document.write('<table class="cal_calendar"><tr><th colspan="7">'+months[mois]+' '+year+'</th></tr><br>');
    document.write('<tr class="cal_d_weeks"><th>Dim</th><th>Lun</th><th>Mar</th><th>Mer</th><th>Jeu</th><th>Ven</th><th>Sam</th></tr><tr>'); 
    week = 0;

    for(i=1;i<=beg_j;i++)
    {
            var beforemonth = months[month-1]; 

           document.write('<td><div class ="divday" />'+(days_in_month[month-1]-beg_j+i)+'</div></td>');
            week++;
    }
    for(i=1;i<=total;i++)
    {
            if(week==0)
            {
                document.write("<tr>");
            }

            if(day==i && moisaujorduiu==month) //si le jour = le jour de aujordhui est si le mois = mois aujordui 
            {

                document.write("<td><b><div class ='divtoday' onclick='open_popup(\""+i+" "+months[month]+"\")' href='#'>"+i+"</div><b></td>"); //day of today
            }
            //les autre jours
            else
            {

                document.write("<td><div class ='divday' onclick='open_popup(\""+i+" "+months[month]+"\")' href='#'>"+i+"</div></td>");
            }
            week++;
            if(week==7)
            {
                    document.write('</tr>');
                    week=0;
            }
    }

        //pour les jour du prochain mois

         for(i=1;week!=0;i++)
        {
                var nextmonth = months[month+1];
                document.write('<td><div class ="divday">'+i+'</td>');
                week++;
                if(week==7)
                {
                        document.write('</tr>');
                        week=0;
                }
        }
    document.write('</table>');
}
```

Comment: Aproveite e simplifique seu HTML, use o valor dos meses diretamente, ex.: calendar(1); ao invés de ficar criando uma variável desnecessária.

Comment: Utilizei o seu codigo assim http://jsfiddle.net/L6qwmbqz/2/ mas nao funciona. Sim simplifiquei o codigo html, fica melhor assim.

Comment: Você trocou apenas uma linha pelo IF né?? Editei minha resposta com a função inteira, altere pela sua e teste. Eu testei aqui e esta tudo certo.